# Invoke-ASCmd : The term 'Invoke-ASCmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable

Tags: powershell, deployment, ssas

we face an issue with below when run it within ps1 file:

Invoke-ASCmd : The term 'Invoke-ASCmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable

but if run Invoke-ASCmd in powershell, it works. so strange. 
does anyone can help on this?

Comment: `help about_Command_Precedence`

Answer (score 2):

Install-module -AllowClobber -Name SqlServer

Comment: After I overcame proxy issues with`-proxy` and `-proxycredentails` switches and managed to install this (verified with `Get-InstalledModule`), I still get the same error